# Adding value labels to hvplot.bar

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot

Using the [hvplot tutorial](https://holoviz.org/tutorial/Basic_Plotting.html) we are trying to generate a bar plot with values as labels on the bars itself.
The bar plot is generated using the following code

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import hvplot.pandas
df = dd.read_parquet('data/earthquakes.parq').persist()  
df.magType.value_counts().compute().to_frame().hvplot.bar()
```

[image]

How can we add the value of the bars on the bar itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use holoviews [hv.Labels()](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/matplotlib/Labels.html) to add value labels to your data.


You create the labels separately and [use the * symbol to overlay your labels](http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/bokeh/Overlay.html) on your plot.


**Here's a working example:**

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas

# create some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'],
    'col2': np.random.rand(3)
})

# create your plot
plot = df.hvplot(kind='bar', x='col1', y='col2', ylim=(0, 1.2))

# create your labels separately
# kdims specifies the x and y position of your value label
# vdims specifies the column to use for the value text of your label
labels = hv.Labels(data=df, kdims=['col1', 'col2'], vdims='col2')

# use the * symbol to overlay your labels on your plot
plot * labels
```

**Final result:**

[image]

Comment: We tried to use the `yoffset` as shown in [Labels guide](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/matplotlib/Labels.html) 
but then graph disappears - what are we doing worng?
` labels = hv.Labels(data=df, kdims=['col1', 'col2'], vdims='col2').opts(hv.opts.Labels(yoffset=0.05))`

Comment: i ran into the same problem, maybe you can ask about your issue here: https://gitter.im/pyviz/pyviz These are the developers and they are quite responsive to problems, maybe they know a solution to this.

Comment: There is an [open issue #3892 on github](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/3892)

Comment: If you switch the holoviews backend to plotly using hv.extension('plotly') then yoffset is working. So within holoviews it is working for plotly, but not for the bokeh backend.

Comment: Thx for the update, unfortunately I don't have plotly in my environment